# Why Thread.Start method is blocked when CPU load is high?

Tags: c#, multithreading, benchmarking

For test purposes I write CPU stress program: it just do N for-loops in M threads.
I run this program with large number of threads, say 200.
But in Task Manager I see that threads counter not exceed some little value, say 9 and a Thread.Start methods *waits for finish previous running threads*.

This behavior seems like a ThreadPool behavior, but I expect that regular `System.Threading.Thread` must start anyway without waiting for some reason.

Code below will reproduce this issue and have an option for workaround:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace HeavyLoad
{
    class Program
    {
        static long s_loopsPerThread;
        static ManualResetEvent s_startFlag;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long totalLoops = (long)5e10;
            int threadsCount = 200; 

            s_loopsPerThread = totalLoops / threadsCount;

            Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsCount];

            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(IntensiveWork);
                t.IsBackground = true;
                threads[i] = t;
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating took {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // *** Comment out s_startFlag creation to change the behavior ***
            // s_startFlag = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (var thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Start();
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting took {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            if (s_startFlag != null)
                s_startFlag.Set();

            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (var thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting took {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void IntensiveWork()
        {
            if (s_startFlag != null)
                s_startFlag.WaitOne();

            for (long i = 0; i < s_loopsPerThread; i++)
            {
                // hot point
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Case 1:** If s_startFlag creation is commented, then starting threads immediately begins a high intensive CPU work. In this case I have a small concurrency (around 9 threads) and all the time I hold on thread starting code:

```
Creating took 0 ms
Starting took 4891 ms
Waiting took 63 ms
```

**Case 2:** But if I create s_startFlag, all new threads will wait until it will be set. In this case I successfully start all 200 threads concurrently and get expected values: little time for a start and much time for a work and number of threads in Task Manager is 200+:

```
Creating took 0 ms
Starting took 27 ms
Waiting took 4733 ms
```

**Why threads refuse start in first case? What kind of limitation I exceed?**

System:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional
- Framework: NET 4.6
- CPU: Intel Core2 Quad Q9550 @ 2.83GHz
- RAM: 8 Gb

Comment: Possibly you're looking at a hardware/OS limitation? For instance, disk I/O would definitely have max channel limits, which would effectively result in some threads being blocked...

Comment: This test not involve any disk I/O. It's seems like limitation "you have CPU load 95%, so I don't start any thread". But I don't heard about such limitations. Why this happen?

Comment: Question is, what exactly is causing the CPU load? The CPU is doing something, that's what the instrumentation is telling you. Running a profiler would make great sense at this point.

Comment: No. I know why CPU is high load - I make it specially (long loop). My question is why threads don't start quickly.

Comment: So are you spinning? Or spinning and waiting? Spinning would definitely cause CPU to max out. So what if you do a spin-and-wait approach? Maybe even a 50ms sleep might let the CPU get enough oxygen to spin up the rest of your threads.

Comment: I think the reason in the first case is that because of context switching between threads, Your example never needed more than 9 concurrent threads. You can verify this just by sleeping inside IntensiveWork api may be for 5 min. And I am pretty sure that you will see 200 threads in first case also. Or rather than sleep, define one mutex and do lock as soon as you enter the intensiveWork.

Comment: My guess is too that because the thread just start to take away processing power your own thread slows down massively. Maybe experiment with thread-prioritys and see whats happening then. Also you CPU has 4 cores and I don't really believe that every core can handle much more than two of these threads when the cputime is equally shared. Also the counter shows 9... In my opinion this is 1 mainthread+4*2 threads.

Comment: Be cautious: randomly messing around with thread priorities can lock up your system.  I have to mention that spinning is not a valid CPU stress, in any case, nor is it a technique to show anything more useful than "so this is why people don't declare hundreds of threads and use worker pools." =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some research and now I see that high CPU load really have strong affect to the thread starting timings.

First: I set totalLoops to 100 times bigger value for have more time of observation. I saw that threads not limited but very slowly created. 1 thread start in 1-2 seconds!

Second: I explicitly bind a main thread to CPU core #0 and working threads to cores #1, #2, #3 using of `SetThreadAffinityMask` function (https://sites.google.com/site/dotburger/threading/setthreadaffinitymask-1).

```
Stopwatch watch;
using (ProcessorAffinity.BeginAffinity(0))
{
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(IntensiveWork);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        threads[i] = t;
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Creating took {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

and

```
using (ProcessorAffinity.BeginAffinity(1, 2, 3))
{
    for (long i = 0; i < s_loopsPerThread; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Now main thread has own dedicated CPU core (in the process boundaries) and worker threads starting after ~10 milliseconds (totalLoops = 5e10).

```
Creating took 0 ms
Starting took 2282 ms
Waiting took 3681 ms
```

Additionally, I found this sentence in MSDN:

> When you call the Thread.Start method on a thread, that thread **might
>   or might not start executing immediately**, depending on the number of
>   processors and the number of threads currently waiting to execute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50(v=vs.110).aspx

**Conclusion:** Thread.Start method a very sensitive to number of actively working threads. It could be a very strong performance impact - slowing in hundreds times.